# Is there a way to disable backup file generation in HSQLDB?

Tags: java, jdbc, backup, hsqldb, hypersql

So we are using HSQLdatabase as temporary storage to offload to disk for doing some calculation, we will be doing some bulk operations on merge statements(upsert/ insert or update)and size of database file in some cases reach as high as 70+gb. Is there a way to disable .backup file creation in HSQL db? we are fine with instances of DB corruption or node crash. Are there any properties that we can rely on for such use cases? I referred to Bulk Inserts, Updates and Deletes from document and will set up my properties accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The backup file generation is for persistence durability. When you don't need durability you can turn it off with this SQL statement:

```
SET FILES LOG FALSE
```

Or the database connection property, `hsqldb.log_data`

```
hsqldb.log_data=false
```

The data is still consistent with this setting but the changes will be lost in case of process termination.

See the guide http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/deployment-chapt.html#dec_bulk_operations